# Better ways of concating the value of columns

Tags: query-performance, oracle-11g-r2, query, plsql, syntax

I have a table with below structure and sample data:

```
create table CUSTOMER_TEST
(
  customer_num Number,
  rel_one      Number,
  rel_two      Number,
  rel_three    Number,
  rel_four     Number
)

   Customer_num    Rel_one     Rel_two        Rel_three        Rel_four 
 --------------- ----------- -------------  --------------  --------------
    1               7           12             1000               5
    2               2            1               0                12
    3              12           99              13                0
```

The desired result is this :

```
   Customer_num    Rel_one     Rel_two        Rel_three        Rel_four      Relation_Code
 --------------- ----------- -------------  --------------  --------------  ***************
    1               7           12             1000               5           L07R12C99S05
    2               2            1               0                12          L02R01C00S12
    3              12           99              13                0           L12R99C13S00
```

What I've written is this :

```
select   customer_num,
         rel_one , 
         rel_two,
         rel_three,
         rel_four,
       'L' ||
       case 
         when   rel_one > 99 then '99'
           else lpad(  rel_one,2,0) end ||
       'R' ||
       case
         when   rel_two > 99 then '99'
           else lpad(  rel_two,2,0) end ||
       'C' ||
        case
         when   rel_three > 99 then '99'
           else lpad(  rel_three,2,0) end  || 
        'S' ||
                case
                 when   rel_four > 99 then '99'
                   else lpad(  rel_four,2,0) end as relation_code            
                  
from customer_test ;
```

Does anybody have a better idea ? rather than using this much case statement ..

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Akina , It does.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=326a08d152826914f25966afa98924f2

Comment: What is unclear? LEAST returns either actual value (if it is less than 99) or 99. Returned value is formatted to 2-digit string with leading zero and finally it is concatenated. That's all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select   customer_num,
         rel_one , 
         rel_two,
         rel_three,
         rel_four,
       'L' || lpad(LEAST(rel_one,   99), 2, 0) ||
       'R' || lpad(LEAST(rel_two,   99), 2, 0) ||
       'C' || lpad(LEAST(rel_three, 99), 2, 0) ||
       'S' || lpad(LEAST(rel_four,  99), 2, 0)  as relation_code                  
from customer_test ;
```

I hope that none value can be NULL or negative.

Comment: That was great , Thanks . And no there are no null values